# Using base R to query adjacent rows

Tags: r

I have a dynamic data frame that will look similar to the following;

```
Identifier  Letter  Position
       001       A         1
       001       B         2
       001       C         3
       001       D         4
       002       A         1
       002       B         2
       002       C         3
       003       B         1
       004       C         1
       004       D         2
       005       A         1
```

The data frame will refresh and the data can appear in any order with any combination of letters and positions. There are also the following variables;

1. `sequence`, for which the value in this example is ‘BC’.
2. `starting_position`, for which the value in this example is ‘2’.

I would like to use base R to extract all unique identifiers, which have a ‘B’ at position `[starting_position]` AND a ‘C’ at the next adjacent position i.e.`[starting_position+1]`.

The variable could be of any length e.g. the user could instead input ‘ABC’ or  ‘B’ or ‘CD’ and the query would have to update accordingly.

Note that I’m using software that doesn’t let me install additional packages on our server, so and solution should be in **Base R** only.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is first to generate the string to match, move to the query position, then use `grepl('^${querystring}',target)` to match it.

The data has to be sorted by position though, so something like this might work:

```r
library(dplyr)

## make data
a <- structure(list(Identifier = c("001", "001", "001", "001", "002", 
                                   "002", "002", "003", "004", "004", "005"), 
                    Letter = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "D", "A"), 
                    Position = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), 
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
s <- 'BC'
p <- 2

## dplyr
a %>% 
  arrange(Position) %>%
  group_by(Identifier) %>% summarise(String = paste(Letter, collapse=''))%>%
  mutate(SubString = substr(String, p, nchar(String)),
         found = grepl(paste0('^',s), SubString))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   Identifier String SubString found
#>   <chr>      <chr>  <chr>     <lgl>
#> 1 001        ABCD   BCD       TRUE 
#> 2 002        ABC    BC        TRUE 
#> 3 003        B      ""        FALSE
#> 4 004        CD     D         FALSE
#> 5 005        A      ""        FALSE

## base
searchmat <- data.frame(String = tapply(a$Letter, a$Identifier, paste, collapse = ''),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
searchmat$Identifier <- rownames(searchmat)
searchmat$SubString <- substr(searchmat$String, p, nchar(searchmat$String))
searchmat$found <- grepl(paste0('^',s), searchmat$SubString)
searchmat
#>     String Identifier SubString found
#> 001   ABCD        001       BCD  TRUE
#> 002    ABC        002        BC  TRUE
#> 003      B        003           FALSE
#> 004     CD        004         D FALSE
#> 005      A        005           FALSE
```

Created on 2018-07-31 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks very much! Apologies to be a pain, do you know how I can do this in base r? I’m using software that doesn’t let me install additional packages on our server.

Comment: Also, the table itself is dynamic so will be refreshed frequently. I’m not sure I’d be able to define a sort as above..

Comment: Added a solution using base R. What sort of updates to the table will you be expecting? Will positions be out of order or will they be sequential?

Comment: Thanks so much! Will test this now. They could be out of order.

Comment: Sorry, why is P <- 2? The starting position in this example is 1, therefore it should be looking for identifiers for which there is a letter B is at position 1 and a letter C at position 2

Comment: That's a variable that you can change. Using p=1 in this example will return no matches for the data you provided. I used an arbitrary position that will return an expected match.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How should I get around the sorting issue?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I don't think this quite does what I need it to do given the fact that my table is likely to change on refresh.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know that your table updates dynamically. A solution could be to slice a static table by Identifier and then perform the search. There are likely more efficient methods for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
sequence <- "BC"
starting <- 2

df2 <- df %>%
    filter(Position >= starting)%>%
    group_by(Identifier) %>%
    arrange(Position) %>%
    summarise(string = paste(Letter, collapse = "")) %>%
    mutate(has_string = startsWith(string, sequence))

df2
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Identifier string has_string
       <int> <chr>  <lgl>     
1          1 BCD    TRUE      
2          2 BC     TRUE      
3          4 D      FALSE     

df2[df2$has_string, "Identifier"]
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  Identifier
       <int>
1          1
2          2

unname(unlist(df2[df2$has_string, "Identifier"]))
[1] 1 2

df2 %>%
    filter(has_string) %>%
    select(Identifier) %>% unlist() %>% unname()
[1] 1 2
```

Here's how it works:

1. `filter` removes rows before the `starting_value`,
2. `group_by` Identifier, so that dplyr acts on the rows with the same identifier together
3. `arrange` rows by position, to put them in the proper order regardless of the order of the data frame
4. `summarize` produces a single column per group containing the `Letter` pasted together into a string. Because of the filtering step, letters before the `starting_value` are removed
5. `mutate` adds a new variable which says whether that the string (made of joined `Letter`s) `startsWith` the `sequence`.
6. Now we can use base R bracket notation, to select the variable `Identifier` from rows where `has_string == TRUE`. You can pass the output through `unname(unlist())` to make it a simple vector.

I noticed that in a comment, you mentioned that you can only use base R. Obviously this answer won't work for you then, but I'll leave I here for others.

Comment: Thanks very much! This looks great but as you’ve noticed, I can’t use additional packages and am still looking for some base r help.